# Java socket program hosted on heroku cannot get InputStream

Tags: java, heroku, serversocket

I tried to upload my chat program to heroku, but client side couldn't get InputStream from server, so it stopped.
What's problem in this? It worked well when I just try in localhost.
It printed "getting I/O stream" but it seems like it stopped while getting InputStream.

Also is it possible to get output from Server.jar?
I cannot check if my program is working well.

Server

```
server = new ServerSocket();
server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port));
System.out.println("server opened in " + ip + ":" + port);

try {
    while (server.isClosed() == false) {
        if (server.isClosed() == false) {
            Socket connection = server.accept();
            Client client = new Client(connection);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception error) {
    if (server.isClosed() == false) {
        error.printStackTrace();
        shutdown();
    }
}
```

Client

```
InetAddress[] dns = null;
try {
    dns = InetAddress.getAllByName("jjabtu.herokuapp.com");
} catch (UnknownHostException error) {
    System.out.println("No domain found");
}

Socket connection = new Socket(dns[0].getHostAddress(), 80);
System.out.println("getting I/O stream");
ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
System.out.println("got I/O stream");
```

Answer (score 0):

heroku supports websockets , but pure socket tcp connection ? I guess they don't support this. you connect to the server using a "router" server in the middle, so it is diferent network topology than when you run this locally.

see this
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-java-websockets